# How to set up an incline

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have a blender scene where I have a set of small steps. I also added two bounding boxes for each step.

[image]

But the problem is that when I build my game in babylon.js my player cannot ascend the steps.

[image]

My question is: is there an "incline" feature that I can add to either the steps or the player, or for both? If there is how do I do that? If not then what do I need to in order to have my player ascend the steps?

Comment: Blender Game Engine? Try Ctrl + B (Bevel), with the correct edges selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need only one collision box for the entire set of stairs, don't bother with bounds for each step, it just makes stuff complicated.

[image]

The black line symbolizes the collision mesh. Set it to invisible. When the character goes up the stairs, there won't be any issues, and it looks real enough that no-one should notice this standard FPS nuance.

Also, if you use BGE there is a setting for step height under the character physics type.